# jQuery freezing when iterating after keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with jQuery freezing up for multiple seconds on keyup of an input box. I am attempting to show/hide rows of a table based on the value of user input, as well as manipulate some borders with jQuery at the same time.

For example, a user types in '3'. On keyup, all rows with a '3' should remain visible while those without it will hide.
I've isolated the issue to the commented lines of javascript. When active, they are what is causing the issue. Commenting them out is correcting my freezing issue, but the border styles I am trying to achieve are incorrect. Why would this be the case?

JS:

```
$('#narrow').keyup(function () {
    var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.multiples-table tbody tr').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) == -1) {
            $(this).hide();

            $('.table-wrapper').css('border', 0);
            $('.multiples-table').css('border-left', '2px solid #ccc');
            $('.multiples-table').css('border-top', '2px solid #ccc');
        }
        else {
            $(this).show();

            //$('.table-wrapper').css('border', '2px solid #ccc');
            //$('.multiples-table').css('border-left', 0);
            //$('.multiples-table').css('border-top', 0);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="narrow" class="search" placeholder="Filter" value="">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="multiples-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>$10,000</td>
                    <td>$3.40</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn1" Text="Select" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$20,000</td>
                    <td>$5.10</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Select" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're altering the css of the table inside of your `each`, changing it over and over again.  Can't you set a flag inside the loop and then alter the css just once outside the loop?

Comment: One recommendation, try caching queried elements when you can. For example store `$('.multiples-table')` and apply CSS to the variable rather than querying the DOM for elements with class `'multiple-table'` again. For a large number of elements this can make a noticeable difference. Also CSS property `border-left`/`border-right` do not have a `0` as an acceptable value. `none` would be a valid option to set `border-left` or `border-top` to indicate no border. `border-width` on the other hand would have `0` as an acceptable value.

Comment: Tip: `.toLowerCase()` is irrelevant for numbers.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ would greatly simplify your code, but it likely wouldn't solve your problem. A debounce would likely be a good idea here to avoid having to search on each keypress, even ones that happen faster than 50ms.

Answer (score 1):

Try to postpone the css until loop is finished:

```js
$(function() {



  $('#narrow').keyup(function() {
    var shouldSetBorder = false;

    var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.multiples-table tbody tr').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) == -1) {
        $(this).hide();
        shouldSetBorder = false;
      } else {
        $(this).show();
        shouldSetBorder = true;
      }
    });

    if (shouldSetBorder) {
      $('.table-wrapper').css('border', '2px solid #ccc');
      $('.multiples-table').css('border-left', 0);
      $('.multiples-table').css('border-top', 0);
    } else {
      $('.table-wrapper').css('border', 0);
      $('.multiples-table').css('border-left', '2px solid #ccc');
      $('.multiples-table').css('border-top', '2px solid #ccc');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="narrow" class="search" placeholder="Filter" value="">
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table class="multiples-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>$10,000</td>
        <td>$3.40</td>
        <td>
          <asp:Button ID="btn1" Text="Select" runat="server" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$20,000</td>
        <td>$5.10</td>
        <td>
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Select" runat="server" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```